# Connect to a stored procedure with parameters on a server in PowerBI

Tags: azure, powerbi

I wrote a stored procedure which takes in a given string from an user (within the report) as a parameter and searches through tables and attributes (Information Schema) stored on a SQL server in Azure.
I'd like to display the results in PowerBI desktop w/o the need of downloading all the data/bd.
I don't have an access to PowerBI embed.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Paginated Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-paginated-report) (aka SSRS reports, aka RDL Reports) can do this.

But Power BI Reports would need to load all the data into the Power BI DataSet, or refer to the underlying tables/views in DirectQuery for interactive filtering.

Comment: Can I use Information Schema to search through the the underlying tables?